# Qual é a diferença prática de um git merge e um git pull?

Tags: git

No dia-a-dia desenvolvendo eu sempre uso `git pull` para pegar as alterações do branch principal, aonde os desenvolvimentos paralelos são mesclados.
Porém alguns IDEs como Netbeans, implementam o comando "git merge -ff origin develop" por exemplo ao botão de atualizar do [git toolbar](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/51604/git-toolbar).

Eu poderia estar fazendo `git merge`, teria o mesmo efeito, mesclar as alterações dos outros desenvolvedores ao meu branch de implementação, eu teria o mesmo efeito, já que:

> para atualizar seu repositório local com a mais nova versão, execute 
>   `git pull` na sua pasta de trabalho para obter e fazer merge (mesclar)
>   alterações remotas. para fazer merge de um outro branch ao seu branch
>   ativo (ex. master), use `git merge <branch>`, em ambos os casos o git
>   tenta fazer o merge das alterações automaticamente.

*Fonte: http://rogerdudler.github.io/git-guide/index.pt_BR.html*

**Mas na prática, qual seria a diferença entre o `git pull` e o `git merge`, na situação de atualizar meu trabalho local com alterações de outro branch?**

Em ambos os casos será feito um merge no final, ou gerará uma resolução de conflito para acertar. Porém fico na dúvida se usar git pull ao invés do git merge é de fato o correto e quais implicações isso pode causar.

Então seria possível mostrar casos que diferencie a utilização exclusiva de ambos?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`git pull` é a mesma coisa que `git fetch` + `git merge`

Exemplo:

> ```
> git pull origin master
> ```

é a mesma coisa que:

> ```
> git fetch origin
> git merge origin/master
> ```

**Documentação em**
https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-pull.html