# Qual a diferença entre o comando git pull e clone?

Tags: git

Em pesquisas realizadas na internet não encontrei uma resposta em definitivo qual diferença entre os comandos `git pull` e `git clone`?.
Tendo em vista que cada um faz a função de trazer o repositório remoto para o local.

Comment: O clone vc faz da primeira vez, pois ele vai baixar todo o repositório pra sua máquina (ou seja, vc ainda não tem uma cópia dele localmente, e depois do clone passa a ter). Aí vamos supor que vc já clonou um repositório, e depois de um tempo este foi atualizado e vc quer puxar essas atualizações para a sua cópia local, aí vc usa o pull.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Eles fazem coisas diferentes em relação ao repositório remoto:

**git clone:**

- "copia" todo um repositório remoto para um outro repositório local;
- configura a conexão remota entre o repositório local e o remoto;
- inicialmente copia a branch "default" do repositório (geralmente  "master", "main", etc) do repositório remoto;
- fazemos isso uma vez.

**git pull:**

- "atualiza" a sua branch local com os dados do repositório remoto;
- atualiza uma branch específica;
- é necessário já ter o respositório local e configurado;
- é feito sempre que precisa atualizar o repositório local.

Referências: [git clone](https://github.com/git-guides/git-clone) | [git pull](https://github.com/git-guides/git-pull)

Comment: Vale lembrar que muitos serviços mudaram o branch padrão de "master" para "main" (por exemplo, [o GitHub mudou isso em outubro de 2020](https://github.com/github/renaming/commit/4c8e50916922d98617e1c306afc8a8fcbf036a52), então muitos repositórios já usam o novo nome). Outro detalhe é que `clone` sempre traz todos os branches remotos (não só o master), e localmente seta o branch atual (o [HEAD](/q/528332/112052) local) para o mesmo branch que o HEAD do repositório remoto está apontando (que em 99,99% dos casos o pessoal acaba deixando como o master/main)

Comment: Concordo, outra duvida que também possuía referente ao significado desse conceito entre master e main, agora solucionado.

Comment: Posso acrescentar algo? Já vi pessoas no meu trabalho confundirem `git pull` com `git fetch`. _O `git fetch` é o comando que informa seu git local que ele deve obter as informações de metadados mais recentes do repositório original (embora ainda não faça a transferência dos dados – é como verificar para ver se há mudanças disponíveis). O `git pull`, por outro lado, faz isso __E__ traz (cópia) dessas mudanças do repositório remoto._

Comment: @CmteCardeal Já tem aqui: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/232250/112052

Comment: @hkotsubo sim sobre o nome "master" eu editei a pergunta e colocou o repositório "default". quanto ao *"sempre traz todos os branches remotos (não só o master"* desculpe mas isso não é verdade. Se fizer o git clone ele irá trazer só o repositório default, por exemplo  master, se a seguir fizer o comando "git branch" vai ver que só tem a branch padrão, não traz todas as branches, pode confirir isso

Comment: Ele traz todos os branches remotos também, rode `git branch -a` pra ver. Tanto que se fizer `git checkout nomebranch`, e assumindo que `nomebranch` é um remoto que ainda não existe localmente, ele já cria um branch local apontando para o mesmo commit do remoto (sem precisar consultar o remoto, pois os branches já estavam no histórico local)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72156

Comment: @hkotsubo eu entendi agora o que quis dizer, eu estou falando no conceito de ter a branch local, atualizada, com o track para o remoto e "pronta" para ser alterada, o que não é bem o que acontece... o clone faz isso tudo só com a branch default (vamos supor aqui "master"). A informação do track das branches está lá, mas não as branches "prontas" por assim dizer... se fizer um `git checktou nome-da-branch` ela vai ficar co "HEAD detached", ou seja, eu tenho só o track... é como fazer o `fetch` e não fazer o `pull`, vais ter o track de todos os commits mas não os commits em si, entende?

Comment: mas sim, ele clona a informação das branches, e tem no mínimo o nome e track para o remoto no repositório local após fazer o git clone, que como mencionou da pra ver com `git branch -a`, mas não tem "a branch local" e foi nesse sentido que eu comentei :)

Comment: Segue o link da documentação referente aos comandos citados:

Git Clone: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone/pt_BR

Git Pull: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull/pt_BR

Answer (score 0):

"Sim. Eles são basicamente os mesmos(Criar diretórios). Porém a diferença está em o que o git clone configura os rastreamentos remotos adicionais para cada ramificação no repositório clonado (visível usando git branch -r ) e cria uma ramificação ativa do repositório clonado , o git clone é usado apenas quando vamos carregar o projeto pela primeira vez.

já o git pull - também uma combinação de git fetch+ git merge - atualiza a cópia local com novas confirmações/commit no repositório remoto. E mais usado se você estiver colaborando com outras pessoas em um projeto.Resumindo : O git clone baixando os arquivos mais atualizado do diretório e git pull está atualizando os arquivos." Por Igor Leonardo dos Santos

Answer (score 0):

`git clone` é como você obtém uma cópia local de um repositório existente para trabalhar. Geralmente é usado apenas uma vez para um determinado repositório, a menos que você queira ter várias cópias de trabalho dele por perto. (Ou deseja obter uma cópia limpa depois de estragar o seu local ...)

`git pull`(ou `git fetch` + `git merge`) é como você atualiza essa cópia local com novos commits do repositório remoto. Se você estiver colaborando com outras pessoas, é um comando que você executará com frequência.

Espero que tenha ficado claro.

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).